# Colcon: How to change the Cmake path

Tags: ros, fish, ros2, colcon

While installing [ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/macOS-Development-Setup.html) on MacOS, I encountered some problem with Colcon. It seems that it uses the wrong Cmake path.

Running

```
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-skip-by-dep python_qt_binding
```

causes the following error:`make: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.25.0/bin/cmake: No such file or directory`

Full Output:

```
Starting >>> ament_package
Starting >>> ament_lint
Starting >>> gtest_vendor
Starting >>> fastcdr
Starting >>> ament_cppcheck
Starting >>> iceoryx_hoofs
Starting >>> osrf_pycommon
Starting >>> osrf_testing_tools_cpp
--- stderr: fastcdr                                                                                                                  
make: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.25.0/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< fastcdr [0.50s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp [0.49s]
Aborted  <<< osrf_pycommon [0.50s]
Aborted  <<< ament_cppcheck [0.51s]
Aborted  <<< ament_lint [0.53s]
Aborted  <<< ament_package [0.54s]
Aborted  <<< gtest_vendor [0.53s]
Aborted  <<< iceoryx_hoofs [0.68s]                             

Summary: 0 packages finished [2.13s]
  1 package failed: fastcdr
  7 packages aborted: ament_cppcheck ament_lint ament_package gtest_vendor iceoryx_hoofs osrf_pycommon osrf_testing_tools_cpp
  3 packages had stderr output: fastcdr gtest_vendor iceoryx_hoofs
  310 packages not processed
[2.326s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_notification.desktop_notification.terminal_notifier:Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/opt/homebrew'
```

The correct Cmake path would be:

```
>>> which cmake                                                                                                             
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.0/bin/cmake
```

Setting the correct path like this

```
set -x CMAKE_COMMAND /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.26.0/bin
```

didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and found I could use the `--cmake-clean-cache` argument to `colcon` to clear the cached CMake configuration:

```
colcon build --cmake-clean-cache
```

This fixed the dependency on old CMake for me, and exposed another build problem to fix.

Documentation for this and other build arguments is in the [colcon reference](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/build.html).